# Need help keep on getting error but don't know how to fix it

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class  Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
    public int compareTo(Person other)
    {
        int diff = getLastName().compareTo(other.getLastName());
        if (diff == 0)
        diff = getFirstName().compareTo(other.getFirstName());
        return diff;
    }

}
```

these are the errors I keep on getting

Cannot find symbol on line 11,11,13 and 13

Answer (score 4):

Probably you want to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

If you really want to implement [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) then you need to define `compare(T, T)` method.

Comment: ok, so how I change Comparator to Comparable, but I got three errors saying cannot find symbol on line 11, and 13.  how would you fix it

Comment: You should import `java.util.Comparable`, implement `Person#getFirstName()` and `Person#getLastName()`, and read any beginner-level book on Java.